# tikz doesn't fill small figures

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, circles, fill

The usual command `\draw[fill=<colour>] (<centre coordinate>) circle (<radius>);` usually works just fine, however, when the radius is very small, for some reason it doesn't work properly anymore.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[fill=black] (0,0) circle (10pt);
    \draw[fill=black] (0.5,0) circle (0.01pt);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which compiles to:
[image]

How can that be fixed? Thank you for your help, it is very appreciated.

Comment: Well, it works if you use `    \fill (0.5,0) circle (0.01pt);`, not sure about the difference.

Comment: @daleif It's strange, trying with what you provided works and it displays only the tiny dot in the middle of the small circle shown in the figure, then the question becomes why does the other method put that "big" circumference around it.

Comment: The line width is much larger than the radius, so there are rounding errors. When you say `\draw[fill] ...` then the boundary will be drawn.

Comment: @EdoardoSerra: Your code works fine for me. The only problem I encoutered is the displayed result in PDF viewer. In Sumatra the output is displayed incorrectly. In Adobre Reader everything seems OK.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is solved in the comments below the question.